# Skyrim A Night to Remember

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps4

I have now played the A Night To Remember questions twice. My follower (I also married him for the convenience factor) Marcurio. I am playing on PS4. First time through, Marcurio followed me into the Grove and when I was teleported back, he was gone. I picked him up at The Bee and Barb, so naturally I checked to see if he was there. Nope. Then went to Solitude where our house is with our two kids. Nope, not there either. I waited 3 days in each location. Nothing. So I went back, reloaded, and the second time around, I told him to wait in my house in Riften. I flew through the quest a second time, came back to Honeyside. Nope. He's gone. Checked The Bee and Barb (again), nope. Went to Solitude again, kids were there, dad no where to be found. How can I complete this quest without looking my follower/hubs?

Comment: What does Marcurio have to do with the quest? At the moment, it sounds like a generic "Lost follower" problem, not linked to the quest.

I also found this [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Marcurio)
"After marrying him, choosing to live with Marcurio involves living at the Bee and Barb"

Answer (score 0):

They do come back to The Bee and Barb, but it can be a random amount of time, sadly. You just have to wait.
See here for the answer:
https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/18epcl/marcurio_has_vanished_how_can_i_get_him_back/

Comment: You should incorporate information from the link rather than just posting the link - emphasize important information etc.

Comment: like the information I posted above it. Some people are looking to criticise everything on this site. It's a shame.

Comment: I'm not trying to criticize, just trying to encourage you to provide more information because there is other information on that link, and not everyone wants to open new pages.. if you can provide more useful information, why not do so